# Why doesn't border-style: double; render?

Tags: css

I have an `h1` on which I've defined the following styles:

```
h1
  { text-align: center;
    border: double black 1px;
    padding: 1em;
    margin: 1em;
}
```

Here's a JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KatieK/Hs3ZQ/

I set the border-style to double, but I'm only seeing a single border rendered.  Why isn't a double border rendering?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`double` displays two straight lines that add up to the pixel amount defined as border-width ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/border-style)).

You'll need to use at least 3px.

```
h1
  { text-align: center;
    border: double black 3px;
    padding: 1em;
    margin: 1em;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Hs3ZQ/6/

Comment: Yeah. I had 1px and that's why it wasn't working for me. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 9):

1px is too thin to render a double border, you'll have to make the border thicker.

```
h1
  { text-align: center;
    border: double black 3px;
    padding: 1em;
    margin: 1em;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Hs3ZQ/3/

Answer (score 5):

For a double border, you need to set a border width of at least `3px` to [see the effect](http://jsfiddle.net/MattiasBuelens/dWfYn/).

Answer (score 3):

Removing of 1px from CSS will work...

```
h1
  { text-align: center;
    border: double black;
    padding: 1em;
    margin: 1em;
}
```

see the updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Hs3ZQ/5/

Comment: That's because then the width defaults to `medium`, which is thicker.

Comment: @BoltClock : yes right... His question is, he gave double as border style but he will see only single border... So if we remove the pixel size ... it will work..